# TikZ, placing nodes with "below of" and perpendicular coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

TikZ lets making

```
\node (node2) [below of = node2,some options] {textlabel};
```

and also lets using perpendicular coordinates:

```
\draw[some options] (node2.south) -- (node1.east -| node3.south);
```

But the joint use of `below` and perpendicular coordinates doesn't work:

```
\node (node2) [below of = (node1.east -| node3.south),some options] {textlabel};
```

Is it about syntax, or is it not possible at all?

And if it is not possible, how to place a node relative to some perpendicular coordinates?

I would obviously like to avoid creating a node at `(node1.east -| node3.south)` and then using its name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK `below of` expects a node name and does not support calculations.
An alternative is library `positioning`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
  \node (B) at (1, 1) {B};
  \node[below=0mm of A.east |- B.south] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If `0mm` is omitted, the distance configured by option `node distance` is used.